# C++ identify running platform (Android, iOS, etc.)

Tags: android, c++, ios, stl, java-native-interface

As part of a multi-platform project (Android & iOS so far), we share a common C++ codebase for mathematical and algorithmic requirements.

As the Android developper, I am facing several problems using the Standard Library (STL) that my collegue uses in the iOS Project.

In my `build.gradle` > `android.ndk` I use : `cppFlags += "-std=c++11"` and `stl = 'gnustl_shared'`

As examples, I cannot use `std::nth_element()` or `std::sort()` from the original STL, I have to include either : `bits/algorithmfwd.h` or `bits/stl_algo.h`.

I went for `include <bits/stl_algo.h>` and so far so good.

Problem is, we share this code base and I would like to know if we can use **flags** to identify the **running platform** so that the code dynamically uses the correct **include**.

Thanks for the help !

### [UPDATE 1]

As noticed by [@andreas-reiff in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933896/c-identify-running-platform-android-ios-etc/33934015#33934015) it is uncleared that I am indeed looking for the **flags** to use in headers files so that the proper include is performed at **compiled time** (and not at runtime).

As stated before, the current platforms are iOS and Android. Which flags can help us identify these platforms ?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up compile time and runtime.

1) Includes are for compile time, so you can distinguish this e. g. via the build configuration and then select the appropriate include. This also is the normal way. Additionally you can swap some files and also use #ifdef directives for functionality that is only available on some platforms.

2) As for run time, it probably is a little more difficult to find out from generic C++, I would recommend to simply inject that information from the calling code: there has to be some place that knows where it is running, that code can then set a property in your code telling it where it is running.

You probably want to go for 1) though to already select your libraries appropriately.

Comment: thank you for your reply ! Yes I want to go for 1), hence my talk about "flag" but I admit my post is too uncleared. I'll update it accordingly.

Comment: You will compile them in different environments, namely XCode (iOS) and Gradle/Android Build. Either those provide preprocessor directives on their own, or you can specify them as additional defines for those 2 separate builds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check your target only once, you may want to include STL headers through a single header dedicated for that.

For example, create a file `stl_includes.h` with following contents:

```
#ifndef STL_INCLUDES_H
#define STL_INCLUDES_H

#ifndef TARGET_PLATFORM
// Prevent builds without defined target
#error Target platform not defined!
#elif TARGET_PLATFORM == TARGET_IOS
// Your iOS headers here
#include <...>
#elif TARGET_PLATFORM == TARGET_ANDROID
// Your Android headers here
#include <...>
#else
#error Invalid build target!
#endif

#endif
```

This makes sure that every build must define a valid target platform and use the correct headers. Unknown or undefined targets will not compile. Define the valid build targets in some global header, preferably in some other header than the dedicated STL header so you can use them in other platform specific features as well.

Comment: Excellent, I was looking for that ! However, I do not know which flags stand for iOS and Android. I am looking for them as well. Thanks !

Comment: @Mackovich You must define the values for valid targets somewhere in your shared code base. Then each target build must `#define TARGET_PLATFORM` with a legal value, either in a target specific globally included header or through project options/makefile depending on your tool chain. Only your project knows what are the valid targets. You could try to rely on some build environment specific definitions, but that is prone to portability issues if your tool chain or platform libraries change.

Comment: but how can I define such flags ? I just don't get how it would work. Where do I specify that this platform has this flag so that I can check the current flag later ?

Comment: @Mackovich Just add `-DTARGET_PLATFORM=1` to your project's cppflags to select your defined platform 1. Define and document legal values in a global header and use those definitions in your code. Command line syntax for preprocessor definitions is the same `-D<your macro name>=<value>` for _most_ compilers.

Comment: okay, I think I get it. In my build.gradle file I can set the CPPFlags. And as stated in my OP, it's currently `"-std=c++11"`. So this is where I should be able to define a flag, right ?

Comment: @Mackovich Yes. _Where_ you put preprocessor directives is tool chain specific, _how_ is pretty well standardized.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/), here's what you need:

```
#ifdef __ANDROID__
    // Android Headers
#elif __APPLE__
    // iOS Headers
#endif
```

Comment: nice ! But the Apple flag seems to concern only MacOS operating systems. I know iOS is based on it but I am not totally sure it's compatible. Will look for it. Thank you for your help!