# How to check OS (Linux or Android) during runtime with Native C

Tags: android, c, linux

I would like to check if the current operating system is linux or android during runtime with native C. Is it possible? Because I have to execute different code depending on the OS.

Comment: Do realize that Android != Linux, and that .so binaries may be for different architectures (ARM vs x86). See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33933896/295004

Comment: Jeah, but in my case I can compile for x86 and ARM. In case of Linux I have to execute a little bit different code to run my application based on this source for android https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-5.0.2_r3/toolbox/sendevent.c. If possible I would like to keep code for both version same and check during runtime with switch case with part of code has to be executed.

Comment: Is your code running in a rooted Android environment or would be run via a Android app? If by app you could just set a variable indicating environment.

Comment: *"Because I have to execute different code depending on the OS."* - You know at compile time. Use the `__ANDROID__`, `__linux` and `__linux__` preprocessor macros. Also see [How to detect compilation by android ndk in a C/C++ file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6374523/608639)

Comment: Is rooted Android version. Looks like the common way is to check during compile time. I hoped to had only one binary for linux and android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure program runs on Android you can check environment variables named `ANDROID_ROOT` and `ANDROID_DATA`. Usually they are present and refer to `/system` and `/data` folders.

**C:**
You can use `getenv` function from `stdlib.h`:

```
getenv("ANDROID_ROOT");
getenv("ANDROID_DATA");
```

**CLI:**

```sh
$ env | grep ANDROID_
```